# catch Error which is thrown inside stream listen

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) plugin to listen to network connection state changes while downloading a large file, if connection state becomes `ConnectivityResult.none` I want to throw `NoInternetConnectionError`and show some output to the user.
problem is when network state becomes `ConnectivityResult.none` catch doesn't catch error and instead I get `Unhandled Exception` in console.

```
void downloadHandler() async {
StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> supcription;

try {
  supcription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen(
    (ConnectivityResult result) {
      if (result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
         print('>>>>>>>>> result is $result');
        // no connection
        throw NoInternetConnectionError();
      }
    },
  );
  // downloading takes some time
  await downloadLargeFile();
  // download completed
  supcription.cancel();
} on NoInternetConnectionError catch (error) {
  print(error.message);
  // do some thing
}
```

}

```
class NoInternetConnectionError extends Error {
      static const defaultMessage = 'no internet connection';

      final String message;
      NoInternetConnectionError({this.message = defaultMessage});
    }
```

console:

```
I/flutter (15433): >>>>>>>>> result is ConnectivityResult.none
E/flutter (15433): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Instance of 'NoInternetConnectionError'
E/flutter (15433): #0      MyTestApp.downloadHandler.<anonymous closure> 
package:anime_app/test_app.dart:26
E/flutter (15433): #1      _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
E/flutter (15433): #2      _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter (15433): #3      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter (15433): #4      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:338:11)
E/flutter (15433): #5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:265:7)
E/flutter (15433): #6      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add  (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:134:11)
E/flutter (15433): #7      _MapStream._handleData  (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:234:10)
E/flutter (15433): #8      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData  (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:166:13)
E/flutter (15433): #9      _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
E/flutter (15433): #10     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter (15433): #11     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter (15433): #12     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:338:11)
E/flutter (15433): #13     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:265:7)
E/flutter (15433): #14     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add  (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:134:11)
E/flutter (15433): #15     _MapStream._handleData  (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:234:10)
E/flutter (15433): #16     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData  (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:166:13)
E/flutter (15433): #17     _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
E/flutter (15433): #18     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter (15433): #19     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter (15433): #20     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:338:11)
E/flutter (15433): #21     _DelayedData.perform  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:593:14)
E/flutter (15433): #22     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:709:11)
E/flutter (15433): #23     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:669:7)
E/flutter (15433): #24     _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1122:38)
E/flutter (15433): #25     _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
E/flutter (15433): #26     _CustomZone.runGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
E/flutter (15433): #27     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
E/flutter (15433): #28     _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
E/flutter (15433): #29     _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
E/flutter (15433): #30     _CustomZone.runGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
E/flutter (15433): #31     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
E/flutter (15433): #32     _microtaskLoop  (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
E/flutter (15433): #33     _startMicrotaskLoop  (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
```

Comment: is it entering the if  `if (result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        // no connection
        throw NoInternetConnectionError();
      }`?

Comment: yes it is, I updated the question to show this . @PeterHaddad

Comment: did you find a solution?